# Detect which element clicked in foreach, jquery

Tags: jquery

How to detect specific clement, that was clicked, when the id's form all elements are the same, in the foreach loop?

In the foreach loop, there is an input:

```
echo " <input class='active' name='notification_id_' id='notification_id_' value='$notification_id''>$notification_id</input> <br />";
```

Jquery code I use detects only first value:

```
var id = $('#notification_id_').val();
```

Comment: `ID` **must be unique** for every _element_. Use `classes` instead.

Comment: Side note, HTML attributes should be double quoted and not single.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you cannot have same id for multiple element. IDs should always be unique (that's why it is called ID). Change all to class and use `this` reference.

Try this:

```
$('.className').click(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `this` like and use class that you can have multiple classes with same name.but id should always be unique

```
$('.my_btn').on('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).val(); 
    alert("Clicked on id :" + id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I cannot believe it was that obvious. BTW, That was a misclick, did not mean to downvote it :(

Answer (score 0):

1.**simple method:**

```
$('.className').click(function(){
alert($(this).val());
 });
```

2.**By your method:**

```
echo " <input class='active' name='notification_id_' id='notification_id_' value='$notification_id' onclick=test(notification_id_);>$notification_id</input> <br />";
```

In

```
function test(var val)
{
  alert(val);
}
```

hope this will give you some solution.

Comment: Thank you everybody for useful hints!